# Mouse Hover in matplotlib candlestick for python

Tags: python, events, matplotlib, finance

I have implemented this example:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/finance_demo.html?highlight=candlestick

I would like to implement mouse hover features for the candlestick so that I can see the candlestick's open/high/low/close either in a popup or a label in a certain panel. I was following along with:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html

Unfortunately, the function:

```
candlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.6)
```

does not have a `picker=True` keyword. Is there another way to implement the mouse hover feature?

Docs for matplotlib.finance
http://doc.astro-wise.org/matplotlib.finance.html

Answer (score 2):

I have already provided an answer which links to some valuable information. Since you want to approach things by looking at the data rather than artists on an axes I thought I would give you a little bit more aid. What I have done is to take the matplotlib candlestick example, and added an on mouse move event which prints the date that the mouse is currently over, and the 3 nearest (in time) stocks. From this point, it should just be a matter of combining the two answers to produce the desired result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
from matplotlib.dates import  DateFormatter, WeekdayLocator, HourLocator, \
     DayLocator, MONDAY, num2date
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo, candlestick,\
     plot_day_summary, candlestick2

# (Year, month, day) tuples suffice as aregs for quotes_historical_yahoo
date1 = ( 2004, 2, 1)
date2 = ( 2004, 4, 12 )


mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)        # major ticks on the mondays
alldays    = DayLocator()              # minor ticks on the days
weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d')  # Eg, Jan 12
dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%d')      # Eg, 12

quotes = quotes_historical_yahoo('INTC', date1, date2)
if len(quotes) == 0:
    raise SystemExit

fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)

candlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.6)

ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')


def on_move(event):
    ax = event.inaxes
    if ax is not None:
        # convert x y device coordinates to axes data coordinates
        date_ordinal, y = ax.transData.inverted().transform([event.x, event.y])

        # convert the numeric date into a datetime
        date = num2date(date_ordinal)

        # sort the quotes by their distance (in time) from the mouse position
        def sorter(quote):
            return abs(quote[0] - date_ordinal)
        quotes.sort(key=sorter)

        print 'on date %s the nearest 3 openings were %s at %s respectively' % \
                        (date, 
                         ', '.join([str(quote[1]) for quote in quotes[:3]]),
                         ', '.join([str(num2date(quote[0])) for quote in quotes[:3]]))


on_move_id = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)


plt.show()
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the help pelson. I modified your original idea enough to get it working how I wanted. Quite similar to this one, except I store it as a dictionary beforehand for easier lookup.